# Holistic C++ memory leak detection

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I put

```
_CrtMemState and _CrtMemCheckpoint()
```

exactly after `main()` function and

```
_CrtMemState, CrtMemCheckpoint(), _CrtMemDifference(), _CrtMemDumpStatistics()
```

exactly before the close bracket } of `main()` and I get some bytes leaks (normal blocks and CRT)

Using `CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` in the same code I do not get memory leaks.
For CrtDumpMemoryLeaks I use _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF so I believe that because I use some external libs (it is a large project) memory released at the end of the program.

So it is possible to achieve the same functionality (CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() and _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF) with CrtMemDumpStatistics()  or it is not possible so CrtMemDumpStatistics it is only useful for local snapshot memory tests?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried Valgrind? I've heard it's one of the most popular for leak detection.

Comment: Valgrind on Windows?  I prefer to use umdh.exe to compare consecutive snapshots.

Comment: @Antimony As I say CrtDumpMemoryLeaks works fine. I know about Valgrind and other leak detectors. 
However my question is if there is a way to do it with CrtMemDumpStatistics and via memcheckpoints? Can CrtMemDumpStatistics be called at the end of the program after memory allocations cleared?

Comment: @Steve-Townsend from a quick view UMDH is an external program that monitor heap allocations. My question is how from inside my code I can call a function (in my case CrtMemDumpStatistics) after all the memory clearings have been done aka in the last stage of program execution -just a bit before finilize-. Is this possible?

Comment: @Paul - I don't know if that is possible, sorry.  As you noted there are likely to be false positives due to allocations you don't control not being cleaned up on shutdown